# Can't replace AppCompatActivity with Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, appcompatactivity

I'm a beginner to android programming.So could not get what the methods are in the MainActivity class. Of course googled it. But didn't find the answer. Every tutorial asking to extend the main class from Activity,but I'm not able to do it. Any answes, explanations, suggestions are appreciated.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. `AppCompatActivity` can be used samely as `Activity` for methods. Please give more information about what error you caused.

Comment: It not showing errors. I'm not understanding what those methods are and what is the purpose of each element in this program. What does AppCompatActivity, onCreate(), onCreateOptionsMenu(), onOptionsItemsSelected() do in this program. I'm complete beginner. So I hope I'd get some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCompatActivity is what you can use instead of Activity for v21+ of the android sdk. 
As for the methods, in your example:

onCreate - infaltes the layout and you can do a lot of the instantiation in this method, read intent extras etc.

OnCreateOptionsMenu - inflates the menu for the view that you have specified in res/menu which appears on the action bar.

OnOptionsItemSelected - you can specify the actions that should be initiated when a menu item is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

[AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) is the latest Activity class (Its inheritance is Activity) that provide compatilibity with old phones (from 2.1+, api 7) so it will follow the [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) (onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroy).

With the AppCompatActivity you can use all the methods from activity and also have access to Fragments (for dynamic UI via SupportFragmentManager), Loaders (for sql queries via SupportLoaderManager), the Action bar (via SupportActionBar).

To Summarized: AppCompatActivity = Activity + Support for old phones.

Comment: and I also want how each method is useful.

Comment: The only mandatory method is the onCreate because you will usually inflate (create from the xml some java's object) the view and to bind textview, button, etc... with findById.

Answer (score 0):

And if you try extends your class to `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated .Avoid this